# I can not get data from the server (node.js + express), on the client through the fetch API

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I get `{ data: data }` on the client using `fetch()` from the `res.render ()` or `res.json()` methods of the server?

1) rendered page

2) `fetch()` is called, data (data) came from the server

3) I want to manipulate them in the `DOM`

**data comes, but they redraw the page and I see the `json` structure**

Server.js

```
let PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);

// not matter
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json());

// this
const data = { 
  array: [1, 2, 3], 
  string: 'string' 
};
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.json(data)
});
```

---

index.ejs(html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>

  fetch('/')
    .then(res => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(obj => console.log(obj));

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code is working correctly.

The problem is that I am taking data from where I am.

Example: I am on this page - `localhost:5000/`, and trying to get data from the same place:

```
app.get(/, function (req, res ) {
   res.json(data);
})
```

and it turns out that first I get the data from the server and the `res.json(data)` method sends it and draws this data on the page, and that's all, nothing more.

If I need to get something, I would prescribe:

```
app.get(/data, function (req, res ) {
   res.json(data);
});
```

### Full code:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('index');
});

const data = { 
  array: [1, 2, 3], 
  string: 'string' 
};

app.get('/data', function(req, res) { // <---
  res.json(data);
});
```

---

```
fetch('/data').then(res => res.json())
  .then(obj => console.log(obj));
```

We start the server, go to the `localhost/`, open the console, and bam!

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
fetch("/", {method: "get"}).then(res => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

You will find that `res` is a BODY object which contains a readable stream and the data in that stream has not yet been read (only the headers have been read).  So, to get that data, you have to use [one of the methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#Body_Interface_Methods_2) that reads it depending upon what type of data you are expecting.

```
res.json()
res.text()
res.formData()
res.blob();
res.arrayBuffer();
```

These are all asynchronous methods that also return a promise.  So, if you just want text:

```
fetch("/", {method: "get"}).then(res => res.text()).then(text => {
    console.log(text);
});
```

Comment: Why are these methods not needed for `socket.io`? They already do it, when we invoke `emit`, or `soocket.io('event', ....)`?

Comment: @MichaelPodlevskykh - http is a stream protocol.  There could be anything as the body of the http request.  It could be a collection of 20 videos which cannot even all be read into memory at once.  socket.io is a message-based protocol.  It defines things as messages and the library for the protocol reads a whole message and presents that to you.  They are just different protocols, designed for different things that work differently.

Comment: Last question. How can i get this data in res.render, second parameter to client, and use their.

`app.get('/', function(req, res) {`
  `res.render('index', { data: data });`
`});`

i think it must json()

Comment: or i need use `post` request?

Comment: @MichaelPodlevskykh - Huhhh?  POST or PUT are for sending data.  Your `fetch()` request is getting data so a GET is perfectly appropriate.

Comment: Sory for one more question. How can i get `{ data: data }` in `fetch()`/ It's important for me now)

Comment: @MichaelPodlevskykh - Instead of `res.render()` which is designed to render an HTML template, use `res.json({data: data})` and then use `fetch("/").then(res => res.json()).then(obj => {console.log(obj);})`.

Comment: @ jfriend00 Thanks, but why on website `expressjs` in official documentation `res.send()` show it can be able to send params)?        || **`When the parameter is an Array or Object, Express responds with the JSON representation:`**

`res.send({ user: 'tobi' })`
`res.send([1, 2, 3])`

Comment: @MichaelPodlevskykh - `res.send()` has been updated in recent versions of Express to be smart enough that if you pass it a Javascript object, it will attempt to turn it into JSON and send the JSON.  I personally find `res.json()` to be more declarative as to the programmer's intention, but either will work.

Comment: @MichaelPodlevskykh - It doesn't work very well on stackoverflow for you to post a question, get an answer to that question, accept that answer, then add more to the question to ask about other parts of your problem.  Questions here need to be one question, one answer.  If you have new parts of the problem you now want to ask about, please post a new question where you describe the specific new question you want help with.  I'm happy to continue to help you, but please continue in a new question, not by continually adding more things to this question.